# plotly regression line R

Tags: r, line, regression, linear-regression, plotly

Problem with adding a regression line to a 'plotly' scatter plot.
I've done the following code:

```
require(plotly)
data(airquality) 

## Scatter plot ##

c <- plot_ly(data = airquality, 
    x = Wind,
    y = Ozone, 
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
    )
c
```

[image]

```
## Adding regression line (HERE IS THE PROBLEM) ##

g <- add_trace(c, 
     x = Wind,
     y = fitted(lm(Ozone ~ Wind, airquality)),
     mode = "lines"
     )
g
```

[image]

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218319/plotly-not-creating-linear-trend-line)

Comment: Good question but I think you forgot the "~" before "Wind" --> "x = ~Wind".
Same for " y = ~Ozone"

Answer (score 16):

I reckon it's caused by the missing values

```
airq <- airquality %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Ozone))

fit <- lm(Ozone ~ Wind, data = airq)

airq %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~Wind) %>% 
  add_markers(y = ~Ozone) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~Wind, y = fitted(fit))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use layout to remove the legend, and trace to add regression line

```
data("airquality")
fv <- airquality %>% filter(!is.na(Ozone)) %>% lm(Ozone ~ Wind,.) %>% fitted.values()

airquality %>% filter(!is.na(Ozone)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Wind, y = ~Ozone, mode = "markers") %>% 
  add_markers(y = ~Ozone) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~Wind, y = fv, mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(showlegend = F)
```

[image]