# Creating ribbons with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I need to draw two slopes of acceleration-vs-mpg over the scatter plot,
one slope for light cars and one slope for heavy cars. I created this:

```
cars_light <- cars_log[cars_log$log.weight. <= log(mean(cars$weight)), ]
cars_heavy <- cars_log[cars_log$log.weight. > log(mean(cars$weight)),]
cars_log$wt_cat <- ifelse(cars_log$log.weight. > log(mean(cars$weight)), 'heavy', 'light')
```

Until now I have created the scatter plot by doing this:

```
    plot_ly(
  data = cars_log,
  type = "scatter",
  x = ~log.acceleration.,
  y = ~ log.mpg.,
  color = ~ factor(wt_cat),
  colors = c("#8bc34a", "#ff5722"),
  marker = list(size = 10, opacity = 0.6)
) %>%
  layout(title = "Heavy cars VS light cars")
```

Which gives me this result:

[image]

Now, I want to create a slope for heavy cars and another one for light cars, I know that I need to use add_ribbons trace of plotly but I can't figure it out how to generate that. I am having problems computing lm with plotly.
I could do the same with ggplot but I don't know how to do that with plotly..

```
    ggplot(cars_log, aes_string('log.acceleration.', 'log.mpg.')) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(wt_cat))) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', aes(color = factor(wt_cat)))
```

This is a sample of my data:

```
    > cars_log[1:5,]
  log.mpg. log.cylinders. log.displacement. log.horsepower. log.weight. log.acceleration. model_year origin
1 2.890372       2.079442          5.726848        4.867534    8.161660          2.484907         70      1
2 2.708050       2.079442          5.857933        5.105945    8.214194          2.442347         70      1
3 2.890372       2.079442          5.762051        5.010635    8.142063          2.397895         70      1
4 2.772589       2.079442          5.717028        5.010635    8.141190          2.484907         70      1
5 2.833213       2.079442          5.710427        4.941642    8.145840          2.351375         70      1
```

Comment: Have you tried `ggplotly`?

Comment: Not yet, I was trying to solve it with plotly only..

Comment: Please include a minimal set of sample data with your post so it is easier to reproduce what you have. You can use `dput` (as in `dput(mtcars)`), which will make it easier for people to cut/paste your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `add_ribbons()` function. Its main three arguments are:

- `data` the data
- `x` x values
- `ymin` the lower bound of the ribbon
- `ymax` the upper bound of the ribbon

Due to lack of a minimal data set, I took this one: [plotly regression line R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593153/plotly-regression-line-r) which was used in a close question (i.e. drawing regression line in R Plotly). Using this data set, here is an example where the regression is done outside Plotly, its output formatted using `broom::augment()` and then used to create the ribbon:

```
library(plotly)
library(broom)
data(airquality)
airq <- airquality %>% 
      filter(!is.na(Ozone))
fit <- lm(Ozone ~ Wind, data = airq)
airq %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~Wind, name = 'Scatter') %>% 
  add_markers(y = ~Ozone) %>% 
  add_ribbons(data = augment(fit,se_fit = TRUE),
              ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
              ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
              line = list(color = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.05)'),
              fillcolor = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.2)',
              name = '95% ribbon')
```

Which gives the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Hey all, I used the tip here to put a ribbon on some graphs at the bottom of my Shiny page (http://michaelvonplato.shinyapps.io/covidDeaths) - any idea how to remove the dots on the outer edges of the ribbon? I tried a lot of permutations of the variables with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Michael, you can filter on only the points that are inside the ribbon, and plot these. Of course, you should keep the original (unfiltered) data for ribbon computation. I hope this helps. Otherwise, my advice would be to post a new question. In a comment, your question is not visible to everyone :)

Comment: By the way, you should accept the answer if it solved your question so that it's visible for other people facing the same question as you did. Thanks!