# Visualizing multiple linear regression using R

Tags: r, data-visualization, linear-regression, r-plotly, olsmultiplelinearregression

I am trying to fit and visualize a multiple linear regression model using four variables.

```
fit <- lm(general_data$Bacterial.Contigs ~ general_data$Soil.Temperature + general_data$Time.point + general_data$Year)
```

Here, Time.point and Year are categorical variables, and others are numerical variables.

I created a 3D plot using the following code.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data = general_data, z = ~Bacterial.Contigs, x = ~Soil.Temperature, y = ~Time.point, color = ~Year, colors = c('#0C4B8E' ,'#BF382A'),opacity = 0.5) %>%
  add_markers( marker = list(size = 4))
```

And the plot looks like this:

[image]

How can I add the regression line for the "fit" model in this plot. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593153/plotly-regression-line-r) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You fitted a model with only [additive effects](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/8/8.5), meaning your categorical values only add or decrease your response variables, the slope will not change for the different categories. It's not easy to visualize that on a 3D plot, I suggest you try `ggplot2` .

An example with `mtcars`, you basically placed the fitted values back into the data frame and call a line for the fitted values:

```
dat = mtcars
dat$am = factor(dat$am)
dat$vs = factor(dat$vs)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp + am + vs,data=dat)
dat$fitted= fitted(fit)

library(ggplo2)
g = ggplot(dat) + geom_point(aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) + 
geom_line(aes(x=disp,y = fitted)) + facet_grid(am~vs)
print(g)
```

[image]

Or if you need a plotly:

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(g)
```